# Dragging vertical markLines in Apache echarts

Tags: javascript, css, echarts, apache-echarts

I want to add several vertical marklines to a line chart and allow users to do horizontal dragging, similar to [this Highcharts example.](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jwtLc379/)

Setting `xAxis.axisPointer` is useful in this sense. However, how can I allow the whole vertical line to be dragged on the horizontal line, rather than using the button at the botton as shown below ?

[Here's my attempt](https://codesandbox.io/s/echart-line-vanilla-forked-433026?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

[image: Edit echart-line-vanilla (forked)]

[image]

```
import "./styles.css";
import echarts from "echarts";

const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("app"));

const option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: "time",
    nameLocation: "center",
    nameGap: 20,
    interval: 420000,
    min: 1625741884000,
    max: 1625749084000,
    axisLabel: {
      rotate: 0
    },
    boundaryGap: ["0%", "0%"],
    axisPointer: {
      value: 1625742000000,
      snap: true,
      lineStyle: {
        color: "#ff0000",
        width: 4
      },
      handle: {
        show: true,
        color: "#ff0000"
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: "value",
      nameLocation: "center",
      nameGap: 8,
      interval: 0.33,
      min: 1,
      max: 5.33,
      axisLabel: {
        margin: 24,
        rotate: 0
      }
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      id: "test",
      name: "Average Time",
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      data: [
        {
          value: [1625741884000, 1]
        },
        {
          value: [1625741885000, 1]
        },
        {
          value: [1625741890000, 1]
        },
         ...

      ],
      subSeries: [],
      invert: false,
      type: "line",
      showSymbol: false,
      symbolSize: 5,
      smooth: false,
      color: "#4da6e8",
      lineStyle: {}
    }
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of having 2 `axisPointer` on the same chart. I've been looking for this feature for a while now, but I still can't find a perfect solution. A workaround using `graphics` can be used to achieve something similar to what you want, but it's far from perfect. I still share it in case it's of any help to you.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

let base = +new Date(1988, 9, 3);
let oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
let data = [[base, Math.random() * 300]];

for (let i = 1; i < 20000; i++) {
    let now = new Date((base += oneDay));
    data.push([+now, Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + data[i - 1][1])]);
}

option = {
  grid: {
    top: '40px',
    bottom: '60px',
    left: '50px',
    right: '30px'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    boundaryGap: false,
    axisLine: {onZero: false},
    axisPointer:
    {
      show: true,
      type: 'line',
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    boundaryGap: [0, '100%']
  },
  series: [
    {
    name: 'Fake Data',
    type: 'line',
    smooth: true,
    symbol: 'none',
    areaStyle: {},
    data: data
    }
  ],
  graphic: {
    elements: [
    {
    type: 'group',
    left: 'center',
    draggable: 'horizontal',
    ondrag: function (params) {    
      var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
      var pointInGrid = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);

      var xTime = new Date(pointInGrid[0])

      //get closest value from cursor
      var point = data.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(new Date(curr[0]).valueOf() - xTime.valueOf()) < Math.abs(new Date(prev[0]).valueOf() - xTime.valueOf()) ? curr : prev)

      //console.log('poi', new Date(pointInGrid[0]), new Date(point[0]), point[1])

      var d = document.getElementById('value2');
      d.style.left = params.offsetX+'px';
      d.innerHTML = point[1]
    },
    children: [
    {
      id: 'bar1',
      type: 'rect',
      top: '30px',
      shape: {
          width: 2,
          height: 685
      },
      style: {
          fill: "#ff0000"
      },
      cursor: 'ew-resize'
    },
    {
      type: 'circle',
      top: '740px',
      shape: {
          r:10
      },
      style: {
          fill: "#ff0000"
      },
    }
    ]
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      left: '150px',
      draggable: 'horizontal',
      ondrag: function (params) {    
        var pointInPixel = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];
        var pointInGrid = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pointInPixel);

        var xTime = new Date(pointInGrid[0])

        //get closest value from cursor
        var point = data.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(new Date(curr[0]).valueOf() - xTime.valueOf()) < Math.abs(new Date(prev[0]).valueOf() - xTime.valueOf()) ? curr : prev)

        //console.log('poi', new Date(pointInGrid[0]), new Date(point[0]), point[1])

        var d = document.getElementById('value1');
        d.style.left = params.offsetX+'px';
        d.innerHTML = point[1]
      },
      children: [
        {
            type: 'rect',
            top: '30px',
            shape: {
                width: 2,
                height: 685
            },
            style: {
                fill: "#0000ff"
            },
            cursor: 'ew-resize'
        },
      ]
    },
  ]}
};

myChart .setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 1200px; height:775px;"></div>
    <div id="value1" style="background-color: blue; color: white; position: absolute; top: 280px; left: 185px">0</div>
    <div id="value2" style="background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 280px; left: 605px">0</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `graphic.elements.ondrag` function is quite interesting as it allows to get the value of the series along the cursor. Here on the example, the value is displayed in a div that is above the 'cursor', but it can be displayed in a prettier way somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you need two vertical lines to select data, recommend using the [`brush`](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=candlestick-brush) tool of ECharts.

[image]